# Weird assert failure after a struct free in C

Tags: c, pointers, null, assert, free

I am a beginner in C and I encountered this weird `assert` failure:

assuming we have this setup:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
} Struct;

Struct* new_struct(int id) {
    Struct* s;
    if ((s = malloc(sizeof(Struct))) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    s->id = id;
    return s;
}

void free_struct(Struct* s) {
    if (!s) {
        return;
    }
    free(s);
    s = NULL;
    assert(s == NULL); // no problem here, `s` is NULL.
}

int main(void) {
    Struct* s = new_struct(4);
    printf("%d\n", s->id);
    
    free_struct(s);
    assert(s == NULL); // Causes assert failure.
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

why does the `assert(s == NULL)` inside the `main` function fail but the one at the last line of the `free_struct()` function pass?

I tried to debug what is happening but with no results.

EDIT:
I added `return s;` to the `new_struct()` function but that wasn't the thing that caused this weird assert failure it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to `return s;` in `new_struct`, so the behaviour of your program is undefined.  (Always enable your compiler's warnings!)

But even after you fix this, you will see the same behaviour. And that's beacuse `free_struct(s)` does not modify `main`'s `s`. Arguments are passed by value, which means that `free_struct`'s `s` is completely independent of `main`'s `s`. You change `free_struct`'s `s`, but not `main`'s `s`.

You could use the following:

```c
#define free_struct(s) { free(s); s = NULL; }
```

(No need to check if `s` is `NULL`.)

Answer (score 0):

`assert(s == NULL); // Causes assert failure.`

Code has not changed `main()`'s `s` as calling `free_struct(s);` does not affect the value of `s` here.